# Feature vector as input to an RNN

Tags: python, nlp

For fun and in order to get a deeper understanding of recurrent neural networks, I am writing my own RNN-based syntactic dependency parser from scratch. In this case, each sentence is a sequence of words, from which a sequence of parser actions is to be predicted.

Now if each word was simply represented by a number, this would not be a problem, as there would have been a one-to-one mapping between the dimensionality of the input to the network, and the network's output. However, in my case each word is represented by an N-dimensional word embedding, whereas each predicted parser action is an integer value within a limited space.

This means my network needs to accept a sequence of feature vectors as input, and then output a sequence of integers.

Currently (parts of) my initialization and forward code looks like this:

```
def __init__(self, trans_dim, out_dim, feature_vec_size=1, hidden_dim=100, trunc=4):
    self.trans_dim = trans_dim
    self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
    self.out_dim = out_dim
    self.trunc = trunc

    # U = input -> hidden weights
    self.U = np.random.uniform(-np.sqrt(1./trans_dim), np.sqrt(1./trans_dim), (hidden_dim, trans_dim))
    # V = hidden -> output weights
    self.V = np.random.uniform(-np.sqrt(1./hidden_dim), np.sqrt(1./hidden_dim), (out_dim, hidden_dim))
    # W = s1 -> s2 weights
    self.W = np.random.uniform(-np.sqrt(1./hidden_dim), np.sqrt(1./hidden_dim), (hidden_dim, hidden_dim))

def forward(self, steps):
    # Number of time steps
    t_steps = len(steps)
    print t_steps
    # The initial hidden
    states = np.zeros((t_steps + 1, self.hidden_dim))
    # Output at each time step
    output = np.zeros((t_steps, self.out_dim))

    # Looping through time steps
    for t in np.arange(t_steps):
        print steps[t]
        # This is where the problem is. Indexing U by steps[t] will not work when steps
        # contains floats.
        states[t] = np.tanh(self.U[:, steps[t]] + self.W.dot(states[t-1]))
        output[t] = self.softmax(self.V.dot(states[t]))
```

Which leads to the question -- how can I make my network accept a sequence of feature vectors as inputs, and then output a sequence of integers representing parser actions in each time step?

I am sorry if this is a dumb question; I am merely a novice when it comes to neural networks, but I wish to learn. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking for help w/ the Python code? Ie, how to write code that will make *this* network accept "sequence of feature vectors as inputs"? If so, that would be off topic here. If you have a general question about input types for ANNs, please edit to clarify.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @gung. Yes, I am, and I am sorry that my question is inappropriate. If you know where I can ask this question, please send me in the right direction.

Comment: If you are just asking for code help, presumably [SO]. You can flag your Q & ask the moderators to migrate it for you.